# Load an HTML when another is display without modify him

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Before all, I just want to apologize to my bad English (french school are not so good for practicing other languages ...).

I have a **header.html** on my site. **I cannot modify him** because it's not mine.
I just want to **call an other html (one of mine, that i can modify, we can name it toto.html), when header.html is display** (in other words, it's not a Java functions who call my other html, it's header.html).

I've tried some Jquery functions (like load()), Javascript and even the macro <#include from HTML, but without success.

Thanks to all for your responses.

Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

I have the following files in one directory:

helloworld.html

```
<p>hello!</p>
```

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function() {
            $('#container').load('helloworld.html');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Loading test.html in browser produces "hello!", so check if you jQuery is loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post example here to show us the context and how your page header.html is included in your site ?

I thinks it's not possible to do that : "(in other words, it's not a Java functions who call my other html, it's header.html)"

If you're not able to modify header.html or the way your page is called, it would be difficult to load anything else.

Comment: It's a J2EE app (who belongs to my enterprise).
I have the 2 HTML files in the same directory.

admin_header.html is called automatically by the development platform Lutece (we used it) 
On this [image](http://hpics.li/a6d5624) , all in the red is from admin_header.html.

The list at the right is that I want to add in toto.html

Comment: In fact, like you can see on the image, i can modify the admin_header.html, but if there is an update on this file by Lutece, all my modifications could disapear.
 Is for this reason that I don't want to modify admin_header, and make my own HTML, who add my list after that admin_header.html is display ;)

Comment: I your JSP file, you made an include of admin_header.html ? or is it done automatically ?